# php Toolkit rather than a framework

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I want to make my own php toolkit rather than use one of the many frameworks out there, specially since they follow MVC, which is not what I'm looking for now. I want to start with basics, and putting in mind OO, I want a simple php mysql connect in a separate file (config.php), with the query in another file (index.php)

I tried this, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

config.php in root

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
?>
```

index.php in root

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search" autofocus />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = '" . $search . "'";
$results = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){ ?>
<li>
<?php echo $row['field']; ?>
</li>   
<?php } ?>
```

UPDATE: Please bear with me, my knowledge on this is new. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you should take some time to get familiar with existing frameworks and how they work before you try to build your own?

Comment: If you are interested in "framework pieces" then consider looking at Zend Framework and Symfony2. ZF is a component framework, which means you can use as much or as little as you want. Symfony2 is full-stack, which means that most people use it as-is, but it contains a number of components which can be used standalone like ZF. If you are doing this as a learning exercise then fair enough, but if it is for production, you should _really_ use an existing system.

Comment: I was looking at it the other way round. I want to learn to build my own from the ground up to know and comprehend how other frameworks work. That and learning php gradually. Do you reckon doing what you suggested is better? I think learning a manual transmission would be the first step before automatic.

Comment: Yes, I think learning existing frameworks was a great step forward for me. symfony 1 was very helpful in that regard, though Symfony2 is better structured architecturally. Learn a leading framework - it's a transferable skill - and then do yours afterwards if you are thus inclined.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing `mysql_*` and `PDO`... Write your queries in `PDO` and get rid of that `mysql_*` business.

Comment: Ok, how do I do that, does Michal's solution (below) fit the bill. I tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = '" . $search . "'";
$results = mysql_query($query);
```

use something like

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = :search");
$params = array(':search' => $search);

$res = $stmt->execute($params);

$results = $res->fetchAll();
..
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. I have to say that I'm new with all this. A step back, using the two files above, how do I make sure that my connection and db selection are working fine?

Comment: Changed my connection to a mysql and back to a normal query, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your config.php file is included just print out your $dbh variable after you require statement in index.php

```
require_once 'config.php';
print_r($dbh);
```

You should get some kind of a print out of the handle.

Comment: Thanks Michael, your comment gave me an idea. Went with [this](http://snipplr.com/view/65082/mysql-connection).

Comment: @brbcoding ok. You advised what I shouldn't be using, can you please elaborate/explain what I should be using and how I go about it.